# Query Notification doesn't work for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the following setup:

1. A WCF service which uses the query notification to monitor
   changes on "Table1" say WCFService1
2. Another WCF service which uses the query
   notification to monitor changes on "Table2" say WCFService2
3. Both service use the
   "Start" and "Stop" method called by separate client to start the
   notification
4. A Windows Service client hosted on server which sends request to both WCF service a request to start the notification.

The problem is if the windows service client says WCFService1.Start and then WCFService2.Start, I get a notification from the table that was registered by WCFService2 i.e. "Table2". If I switch them around, then I get a notification only from WCFService1 i.e. "Table1".

This means that I get notification from only one table (which was registered last) where as I am expecting to receive a notification from  the other table. It seems that this whole "Query Notification" doesn't work with multiple notifications on different tables.

Any ideas?